# move element to the right

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a website : viewplus.kr/touch 
and the right part with the articles are too far to the left. If I use margin-left in css, the entire div box is shifted to the bottom, and I can't think of any other solution. Please help!

{html code}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href='layout.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <title>Touch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=templateholder>
        <header>
            <div class=Layout_header><p class="title"><a href="/about" class="fade"> Touch </a></p> </div>
        </header>
        <div class="touchintro">
            <div class=Layout_4>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />

                <p class="subtitle">
                    Just touch.
                </p>

                <p>우리의 Touch가 당신에게 닿기를.</p>
                <br />
                <p><a href="/all" class="fade">Touch to view+</a></p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=Layout_5 style="margin-left: -1px;">
            <p class="articletitle">article1</p>
            <p><a href="/test.html" style="color: #676767" class="fade"><font color="#676767">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, <br /> consectetur, adipisci velit ...</font></a></p>
            <br />
            <p class="articletitle">article2</p>
            <p><a href="/test.html" style="color: #676767" class="fade"><font color="#676767">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, <br /> consectetur, adipisci velit ...</font></a></p>
            <br />
            <p class="articletitle">article3</p>
            <p><a href="/test.html" style="color: #676767" class="fade"><font color="#676767">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, <br /> consectetur, adipisci velit ...</font></a></p>
            <br />

        </div>
        <div class=Layout_1><a href="/apple"><img src="apple.jpg" class="fade" /></a></div>
        <div class=Layout_2><a href="/google"><img src="google.jpg" class="fade" /></a></div>
        <div class=Layout_3><a href="/microsoft"><img src="microsoft.jpg" class="fade" /></a></div>
        <div class=Layout_6><a href="/etc"><img src="etc.jpg" class="fade" /></a></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

{Css code}

```
        @font-face {
    font-family: ngwotf;
    src: url(../NanumGothic.otf);
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: magenta;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: magenta;
}


.subtitle {
    font-size: 200%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
    font-size: 160%;
    color: magenta;
}

.articletitle {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: magenta;
}

.touchintro {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #676767;
}

body {
    font-family: NanumGothic,"나눔고딕",ngwotf,ngttf,ngeot;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}

.templateholder {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: initial;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

    .fade:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

.Layout_5 {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    color: #676767;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}



.Layout_1 {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.Layout_2 {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

.Layout_3 {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

.Layout_4 {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
}

.Layout_5 {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
    link:"black"
}

.Layout_6 {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

.Layout_header {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could provide a snippet that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Your code is quite large, can you cut it down at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving style as `style="float: right;"`to the div. 
It would be great if you show your HTML to us

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your width is set to 50%. 
As soon as you put in a margin it will move the div down.

Get rid of the width on the article div and you can edit the margins.

If you don't like what happens to it in smaller resolutions you can apply the @media method in css.

Comment: How do I get my media query to display half of the page?

Answer (score 0):

find string in code **Layout20_5** and add **style**

Example:

```
<div class="Layout20_5" style="margin-left: -40px;">
```